# classpath problems with eclipse when working with a multi-module maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a spring-boot 2 project with quite a few sub-modules.

Some modules use libraries which include `jackson-databind`. I added exclusions for them. When doing a `mvn dependency:tree | grep jackson-databind`, I have NO `2.2.2` dependencies. Using `mvn spring-boot:run` works flawlessly. However, starting the application in eclipse leads to the error below.

Where should I search for the source of error?

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:777)

The following method did not exist:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module.getTypeId()Ljava/lang/Object;

The method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/somebody/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/somebody/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/somebody/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/somebody/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.8/jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/somebody/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module
```

Comment: Have you defined jackson as dependency yourself with a version? Not using the defaults which are inherited from Spring Boot? Please show your pom file..

Comment: @khmarbaise Culprit was fakemongo, which is used for testing somewhere, and has a transitive dependency to jackson 2.2.2 - IIRC

Answer (score 0):

uhm. Seems that the project was imported incorrectly into eclipse. maybe `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is to blame.

- remove projects from workspace
- remove all eclipse project files (`.project`, `.classpath`, etc)
- put them into `.gitignore`
- import projects via `import maven project`

now it works.

Comment: You should not use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` anymore cause it's EoL for a long time...use default Eclipse M2E Imports...If you have Spring Boot I recommend to use STS in Eclipse...

Comment: yes, but sadly, mvn eclipse:eclipse is still pretty high on search results :/ I was on a vanilla eclipse, so no maven importer was available.

Comment: If you use plain Eclipse without M2E Plugin this is the wrong path...install M2E in Eclipse and work with M2E than you get imports etc. It does not matter what is high on search results.. maven-eclipse-plugin is retired for a long time see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/....